# How to do source ordering?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using `Bourbon Neat` grid framework and somehow i am unable to do source reordering.
i tried reading documentation but it didn't work.
Can someone please explain how source reordering is done?i mean generally how can we shift a div on top which is 100% to bottom and on bottom to to with width 100%.
What kind of `Css` Needs to be used.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shift mixin to change the source order:

http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#shift

If you do this in conjunction with a media query you can shift elements around within a container.